# Quantitative risk assessment model

Tags: r, statistics, simulation

```
N=1000
alpha=0.1 

zerosandones = rbinom(N, 1,alpha)

vector1=sample(c("raw","cooked"),1000,T,prob=c(0.12,.88))
vector1

densf=NULL
densft=NULL

for (i in (1:N))
{   
  if (zerosandones[i]==1 && vector1[i]=="raw") {densf[i] = 1} 
  else {if(zerosandones[i]==1 && vector1[i]=="cooked") {densft[i] <- rbinom(1, 1,alpha*0.2)}
  else {if (zerosandones[i]==0 && vector1[i]=="raw") {densf[i]=0} 
  else {if (zerosandones[i]==0 && vector1[i]=="cooked") {densft[i]=0}}}}}
densft
densf
```

Hey folks,

I am new to R and building a Quantitative risk assessment model. Briefly over here the idea is that we generate a sample of a 1000 0s and 1s and each 0,1 has a raw/cooked associated. all 0s are dropped and we further analyse the 1s. So for example, if there is a one and its raw then the new densf should equal 1 otherwise 0. Similarly, if there is a one and its cooked then the new densft should equal 1 (simulated on the basis of a binomial rv with an alpha of 0.02 in the case above otherwise 0.

That said, that I m in need of some help as the "densf" and "densft" produce a bunch of `NaN` values, place 0s and 1s at the wrong locations. Please help!

Answer (score 7):

Here's an efficient vectorized solution:

```
N=1000
alpha=0.1 
zerosandones = rbinom(N, 1,alpha)
vector1=sample(c("raw","cooked"),1000,T,prob=c(0.12,.88))

# new code:
densf <- as.integer(zerosandones & vector1 == "raw")
densft <- (zerosandones & vector1 == "cooked") * rbinom(N, 1, alpha*0.2)
```

Answer (score 3):

One of the most important things when learning to program in R is to think in terms of vector operations rather than loops. You're getting `NA`s (not the same as `NaN` in R) in your two vectors because you're not filling all the locations: you're only filling locations in `densf` where you have `"raw"`, and locations in `densft` where you have `"cooked"`. What do you want R to fill the rest of the spaces with? `NA` is the default, but you can fill them with something else (zeros, for example) if you want. That's what I've done below.

```
# your code
N=1000
alpha=0.1 

zerosandones = rbinom(N, 1,alpha)

vector1=sample(c("raw","cooked"),1000,T,prob=c(0.12,.88))

# my code
densf <- ifelse(zerosandones == 1 & vector1 == "raw", 1, 0)
densft <- ifelse(zerosandones == 0 & vector1 == "raw", rbinom(N, 1,alpha*0.2), 0)
```

Things to note:

- The use of `ifelse`, which is a vectorized form of `if`.
- The use of `&`, which is a vectorized form of `&&`.
- No loops! Loops in R are slow. Thinking in terms of vectors takes some adjustment, but is almost always better.

When I ran this I got 12 ones in `densf` and 3 ones in `densft`, which is about what I would expect. If this is not what *you* expect, then you need to better explain what you're trying to do here and why you expect something different.

Comment: thank you very much. if i may ask. i actually have to produce the densft for a string of values from 0.2 right upto 0.9. Do you have tips on how should i go about doing that. Or will I have to change 0.2 to 0.25, 0.3 etc.... each time?

Comment: Loops in R are not slow as a general rule. What is done in them can be slow, especially if you make the mistake of growing objects or subsetting data.frames. Of course, vectorized solutions are still better.

Comment: @user2007598 You could write a function that would calculate densft and then just call the function a bunch of times. The distribution of the entries in `densft` is easy to find analytically, though--it would probably be easier to do this with pen and paper than through simulation.